# Is the ManuallyDrop ABI guaranteed to be repr(transparent)?

Tags: rust

The [nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html) says:

> #### repr(transparent)
>
> [...]
> This repr is only considered part of the public ABI of a type if either the single field is pub, or if its layout is documented in prose. Otherwise, the layout should not be relied upon by other crates.

[`ManuallyDrop<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html) is `repr(transparent)`, but its single field is not `pub`. Its docs say:

> [...] This wrapper is 0-cost.
>
> `ManuallyDrop<T>` is subject to the same layout optimizations as `T`. [...]

Does this count as documenting its layout in the prose? Is it safe to assume that I can transmute or otherwise convert (e.g. pointer cast) from `T` to `ManuallyDrop<T>`?

Comment: Yes that does count as documenting the layout, and yes you can make those assumptions in unsafe code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was actually [just clarified](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/88375/files) with today's release of [Rust 1.61.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/stable/RELEASES.md#version-1610-2022-05-19). The documentation of `ManuallyDrop` now specifies (added text highlighted in bold):

> `ManuallyDrop<T>` **is guaranteed to have the same layout as `T`,** and is subject
> to the same layout optimizations as `T`.